# How to get and use temporary security credentials for multipart upload with javascript aws-sdk addressing MinIO server?

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk-js, minio, aws-sts

I have a MinIO server and need to write a simple web application that selects a file and performs a multipart upload with temporary security credentials. I would like to do something like described here: https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/docs/sts/assume-role.md for getting temporary security credentials using some user credentials i created before. But i want to do it using aws-sdk-js. And i am not sure how to do that for MinIO, like pointing to the right endpoint and using the existing user credentials to invoke AssumeRole or some other corresponding function. Afterwards i want to do a multipartupload, with which i am also struggling how to use it.

I have gone through documentation, but i am struggling to use the provided functions with MinIO in the way i want.

AssumeRole: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html

Multipart Upload: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html

I already set up some code to show what i want to do. multipart-upload.js creates a express server that exposes and endpoint for clients to retrieve temporary security credentials, such that i don't have to share any long-term credentials with the client.

multipart-upload.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

var sts = new AWS.STS();

const server = require('express')()

server.get('/openTemporarySession', (req, res) => {
    var params = {
      DurationSeconds: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
      SerialNumber: 'STRING_VALUE',
      TokenCode: 'STRING_VALUE'
    };
    sts.getSessionToken(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     res.send(data);           // successful response
    })
})

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/indexmultipart.html');
})

server.listen(8080)
```

The client selects files and uploads them through a button. The corresponding function gets temporary security credentials from the server and sequentially performs multipart upload.

indexmultipart.html

```
<input type="file" id="selector" multiple>
<button onclick="upload()">Upload with minio</button>

<div id="status">No uploads</div>

<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var sts = new AWS.STS();

  // invoke helper function to get temporary security credentials and perform multipart upload
  function upload() {
    // Reset status text on every upload.
    $('#status').text(`No uploads`)
    retrieveTempCredentials()
    // Get selected files from the input element.
    var files = $("#selector")[0].files
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i]
      uploadFile(file)
    }
  }

  // call endpoint to generate a pre-signed URL for use in uploading file. 
  function retrieveTempCredentials() {
    $.get(`/openTemporarySession`, (data) => {
      AWS.config.credentials = sts.credentialsFrom(data);
    })
  }

  // upload file to MinIO using the presigned url
  function uploadFile(file) {
    var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
      params: {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: file},
      tags: [{Key: 'tag1', Value: 'value1'}, {Key: 'tag2', Value: 'value2'}]
    });
  }
</script>
```

This code does not really work and I need some help to achieve something like this since i am all new to javascript and html.